# Identify $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{99 }\log (1 + \frac{1}{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm looking for hints on how to compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{99}\log (1 + \frac{1}{n})$.

The series in the log doesn't seem to be geometric or anything so there isn't any apparent way to sum it...

What do you think?

Comment: Hints: $$\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)=\log(n+1)-\log n\qquad\&\qquad\sum_{n=1}^{99}\left(a_{n+1}-a_n\right)=a_{100}-a_1$$

Comment: thats a good idea

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{99}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\log\prod_{n=1}^{99}\frac{n+1}{n}=\color{red}{\log 100}.$$

Comment: pi? what does it stand for?

Comment: @Bak1139: the *product*.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{99}\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)=\log\left(\prod_{n1}^{99}\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right)$$